# Page gets refreshed while loading Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am working on an Asp.net project and we have some interfaces to load corresponding reports.

My html code is as follows:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
         /*----html code for selecting parameters----*/

         <asp:Button Text="Submit"  AutoPostBack="False" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" OnClientClick="javascript:return Validate()" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
         /*----Button to check validity and load report----*/

    </div>

    /*----Some html codes----*/

    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CRViewer" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" EnableParameterPrompt="False" ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="True" ToolPanelView="None" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" HasCrystalLogo="False" HasToggleGroupTreeButton="False" HasToggleParameterPanelButton="False" HasDrilldownTabs="False" HasDrillUpButton="False" HasRefreshButton="True" HasPageNavigationButtons="True" HasPrintButton="True" DisplayToolbar="True" />
    /*----this is where report get loaded----*/



</form>
```

after selecting parameters and clicking submit button, the report gets loaded, but the page gets reloaded and all parameters get reset.

How do I prevent the parameters from getting reset?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the whole page from reloading you need to use a updatepanel to do partial postback.

The example would look like this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server>
    <ContentTemplate>
   <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CRViewer" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" EnableParameterPrompt="False" ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="True" ToolPanelView="None" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" HasCrystalLogo="False" HasToggleGroupTreeButton="False" HasToggleParameterPanelButton="False" HasDrilldownTabs="False" HasDrillUpButton="False" HasRefreshButton="True" HasPageNavigationButtons="True" HasPrintButton="True" DisplayToolbar="True" />   
   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />
   </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Make the button the trigger for the updatepanel meaning if you press the button only the part inside the updatepanel will reload so you won't lose any values